# Run Docker by using shell script from remote machine?

Tags: shell, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

Hi i want to up a docker jenkins container and add jobs by using jenkins-CLI command, these process done successfully when i did manually and by using shell script also. But the main problem is when i am trying to execute this script from remote machine docker container is starting but when i am trying to execute commands in docker container from remote machine it's showing error

**cannot enable tty mode on non tty input**

**cannot enable tty mode on non tty input**

My script on docker machine

```
b="branch1"

sed -i "s/master/$b/g" /root/docker/config.xml

#Run docker jenkins base image
docker run -d -P localhost:5000/jenkins_base2

#Printing docker container
export c=($(docker ps))
echo "${c[8]}"
export x="${c[8]}"

sleep 5

#Copying Config file
docker exec -it ${c[8]} bash -c 'scp root@192.168.0.86:/root/docker/config.xml /root/'

sleep 25

#creating job using jenkins CLI
docker exec -ti ${c[8]} bash -c 'java -jar /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/jenkins/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ create-job  $b  < /root/config.xml '
```

script on remote machine

```
ssh 192.168.0.86 sh docker.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ssh` with `-tt` option.

```
ssh -tt 192.168.0.86 sh docker.sh
```